# Can't connect to a specific URL in python

Tags: python, robobrowser

I am trying to connect to the [Heathrow rewards](https://rewards.heathrow.com) site in Python. I'm trying to use the `RoboBrowser` library to scrape data from the page, but my connection attempt raises a `ReadTimeout` error. Every other URL I have done this with (i.e Waterstones, Maximiles) has worked fine.

I have tried connecting with the `requests` and `urllib` libraries, and got the same results with both.

I thought the issue was something to do with SSL verification so I turned that off, but it did not change anything.

You should be able to replicate the problem for yourself by connecting to the URL above in one of the libraries I mentioned.

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser()
browser.open('https://rewards.heathrow.com')
```

Comment: You could improve the question by providing a minimal example which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: try capturing headers browser send when GET request to this URL and then send these headers in your request with python requests.

Comment: @BarryHurley It's so simple that I didn't think it was necessary, but I've added a minimal example now.

Comment: I just tried it via both `requests` and `robobrowser` and it worked fine. Looks like the problem's at your end.

Comment: @MuhammadTahirButt Just tried that, no luck.

Comment: @tzaman That's interesting, do you have any idea what might cause that to happen?

Comment: Tried with `wget`. It hangs during the Initiating SSL handshake: the server never sends a response.

Comment: Works fine for me as well.

Comment: @Chris: probably our version of openssl does not support insecure digets like HMAC-SHA1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments on the question suggested, this was an SSL version issue. The solution was to create an adapter class as shown here: [Choosing The SSL Version In Python Requests](https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/01/Choosing_SSL_Version_In_Requests/).

The code I used to fix the problem is as follows:

```
class SSLAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, ssl_version=None, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_version = ssl_version
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager()
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=self.ssl_version)
```

Then, when creating the RoboBrowser instance:

```
s = Session()
s.mount('https://', SSLAdapter(_ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1))
self.browser = RoboBrowser(parser="lxml", session=s, user_agent=user_agent)
```